# Difficulty understanding nested collections

Tags: java, collections, nested, bytecode

I am working on dynamically generating classes in java using byte-code and then loading the class.  I found this code on a tutorial how to do it.

```
  private int stringConstant(String s) {
        return constant(CONSTANT_Utf8, s);
    }

    private int classConstant(String s) {
        int classNameIndex = stringConstant(s.replace('.', '/'));
        return constant(CONSTANT_Class, classNameIndex);
    }

    private int constant(Object... data) {
        List<?> dataList = Arrays.asList(data);
        if (poolMap.containsKey(dataList))
            return poolMap.get(dataList);
        poolMap.put(dataList, poolIndex);
        return poolIndex++;
    }

    private void writeConstantPool(DataOutputStream dout) throws IOException {
        dout.writeShort(poolIndex);
        int i = 1;
        for (List<?> data : poolMap.keySet()) {
            assert(poolMap.get(data).equals(i++));
            int tag = (Integer) data.get(0);
            dout.writeByte(tag);          // u1 tag
            switch (tag) {
                case CONSTANT_Utf8:
                    dout.writeUTF((String) data.get(1));
                    break;                // u2 length + u1 bytes[length]
                case CONSTANT_Class:
                    dout.writeShort((Integer) data.get(1));
                    break;                // u2 name_index
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
    }

    private final Map<List<?>, Integer> poolMap =
            new LinkedHashMap<List<?>, Integer>();
    private int poolIndex = 1;
```

I don't understand how the map containing the list is being used it doesn't seem like a traditional oop way of doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Traditional OOP way of doing what? How would you do it?

Comment: _"it doesn't seem like a traditional oop way of doing this sort of thing."_ -- why not? The nested list objects are just objects that are being used as map keys. What's not OOP about it?

Comment: wouldnt it be better just to make a class representing whats in the list and using that as the key

Comment: Why? You have a class that *is* the list. What will you have gained?

Comment: it is confusing editing a list that is then contained in a map

Comment: But editing a list in a class in a map isn't? I don't see what's confusing about it-it's a list. Where it lives is immaterial.

Comment: Well it should at least use an immutable wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fragment you've given us, the map is a means to assign a unique index (increasing from 1) to every List you put into it. This index is apparently *only* used in the `assert` to check that the keys are retrieved in the same order they are inserted - which should indeed be the case given that the map is a `LinkedHashMap`.

As far as the given code is concerned, a `LinkedHashSet` would have done as well. Of course we don't know where `constant` etc. are invoked, maybe the indices are used by the invoker.

I see no objections from an OO point of view - there is little OO about this code fragment in the first place.